# Data mismatches in two table in one go

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have two tables in ms access. Basically I want to get all the records which are do not match when combine with `Col1, Col2, Col3` in one go

In other words `inverse` result of following query

```
SELECT * FROM Tab1 INNER JOIN Tab2
ON T1Col1 = T2Col1
AND T1Col2 = T2Col2
AND T1Col3 = T2Col3
```

Tab1

```
T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3

jkl     nnn     qoq  
efg     aaa     wow  
efg     xxx     yoy
abc     iii     ror  
abc     fff     uou
abc     rrr     rr3  
gdg     ppp     123  
abc     www     234 
jkl     qqq     336  
jkl     nnn     utu
```

Tab2

```
T2Col1  T2Col2  T2Col3

jkl     nnn     qoq
efg     aaa     wow
efg     xxx     yoy
abc     fff     uou
abc     iii     ror1 
abc     rrr     kok  
abc     ww1     234  
gdg     ppp     789  
jkl     nnn     utu  
jks     qqq     336
```

Output

```
T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3   T2Col1  T2Col2  T2Col3

abc     iii     ror   abc    iii      ror1
abc     rrr     rr3   abc    rrr      kok
gdg     ppp     123   gdg    ppp      789
abc     www     234   abc    ww1      234
jkl     nnn     utu   jks    nnn      utu
```

Is this possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the result I assume you want the row to return when only one mismatch from these three columns?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tab1 
INNER JOIN Tab2 ON 
(T1Col1 = T2Col1 AND T1Col2 = T2Col2 AND T1Col3 <> T2Col3)
or (T1Col1 = T2Col1 AND T1Col2 <> T2Col2 AND T1Col3 = T2Col3)
or (T1Col1 <> T2Col1 AND T1Col2 = T2Col2 AND T1Col3 = T2Col3)
```

Comment: This type of JOIN expression not supported.